# ReplacementSpan cuts line in TextView

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring

I need to use custom underline for text in my TextView.
I use ReplacementSpan to do this. But it cuts text at the end of the first line.

Here is my `CustomUnderlineSpan` class:

```
public class CustomUnderlineSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    private int underlineColor;
    private int textColor;


    public CustomUnderlineSpan(int underlineColor, int textColor) {
        super();
        this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3F);

        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);

        paint.setColor(underlineColor);
        int length = (int) paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString());
        canvas.drawLine(x, bottom, length + x, bottom, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    }
}
```

This is method to implement `CustomUnderlineSpan` for all text length:

```
public static Spannable getCustomUnderlineSpan(String string, int underlineColor, int textColor) {
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(string);
    CustomUnderlineSpan customUnderlineSpan = new CustomUnderlineSpan(underlineColor, textColor);
    spannable.setSpan(customUnderlineSpan, 0, spannable.length(), 0);

    return spannable;
}
```

And here is setting text to TextView:

```
String text = "Just text to underline Just text to underline Just text" + 
"to underline Just text to underline Just text to underline Just text" + 
"to underline Just text to underline Just text to underline";

textView.setText(getCustomUnderlineSpan(text,
Color.parseColor("#0080ff"), Color.parseColor("#000000")), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Result:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions why text cuts at the end of line?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

Using `DynamicDrawableSpan` instead `ReplacementSpan` solved the problem.
It seems `ReplacementSpan` just cant perform line breaks.

Here is my code:

```
    public class CustomUnderlineSpan extends DynamicDrawableSpan {

    private int underlineColor;
    private int textColor;
    private final float STROKE_WIDTH = 3F;

    public CustomUnderlineSpan(int underlineColor, int textColor) {
        super(DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                       Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {

        return (int) paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text,
                     int start, int end, float x,
                     int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {

        int length = (int) paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString());

        paint.setColor(underlineColor);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        canvas.drawLine(x, bottom - STROKE_WIDTH / 2, length + x, bottom - STROKE_WIDTH / 2, paint);

        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString(), x, y, paint);
    }

}
```